# Is it okay if all answers (collectively) help answer the question they are posted to?

Tags: discussion

For the question posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39377411/initialization-and-updation-of-variable-types), I am at odds. I think that all answers posted collectively answer the question, and some comments deserve to be mentioned as answers too.

I do not want to write a lengthy answer that compiles all the answers together, besides writing comments as well.

What should be done?

Comment: *"I do not want to write a lengthy answer that compiles all the answers together"* - why not exactly?

Answer (score 4):

You don't **have** to do anything.

If you don't feel a single answer should be accepted...then don't.

If you don't want to write up a single combined answer....perhaps someone else will (although, personally, I think you should)....with attribution where appropriate.

The only thing you perhaps *should* do is upvote the answers that helped you.